# Extracting information from mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongoDB and store coordinates in a collection. If I do:

```
 print doc["coordinates"]
```

it returns:

```
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-81.4531344, 28.5287337]}
```

But if I just want the individual longitudes and latitudes, I'm trying to extract it by:

```
print doc["coordinates" : [0][1]]
```

I get nothing printed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with mongoDB, but if that returned structure is a Python dictionary as it appears, you can access the coordinates like this:

```
print doc['coordinates']['coordinates']
```

`doc` appears to be a dictionary of dictionaries, and when you access the element `coordinates`, you get another dictionary back, and inside this dictionary is another key `coordinates` that contains the actual list of coordinates (similarly, if you wanted the `type`, you could say `print doc['coordinates']['point']`).

Assuming they are in `lat, long` format, you could do something like this to pull them into their own variables (this may not suit your case, so feel free to disregard :) ):

```
lat, long = doc['coordinates']['coordinates']
```

Comment: That makes sense, it works for mongoDB collections also. Thanks

Comment: @user94628 No problem, happy it helps. Good luck with everything.